# Read file put info to url do request and get a specific info

Tags: python-3.x

I have a csv file which is having many strings like this

> "drXY:48.94205856,38.48511505","fromXY:48.94167600,38.49207300",distInM:511
>   "drXY:46.54586411,30.64417267","fromXY:46.53338808,30.65455914",distInM:1599 "drXY:50.06436157,31.44526100","fromXY:50.07415641,31.45929694",distInM:1482 "drXY:50.35911942,30.94097710","fromXY:50.33576900,30.95166500",distInM:2706

I need to open this file, tell to read it line by line and put info

I need to exclude "drXY: put only coordinates then place "|" this symbol and do the same with "fromXY:

As a response i need to get distance and radius then put this data into the file and write for each line which passed distInM near the response from URL

I can grant you my API key to test and give an answers as much as I can.

Code i've tried

```
import requests as req

with open("query4.txt", "r") as f_input:
     content = f_input.read()
     a = content[:].split(',')
     print(a)

     data = {'coordinates': '38.48511505, 48.94205856' '|' '38.49207300, 48.94167600', 'profile': 'driving-car'}
     url = "https://api.openrouteservice.org/directions?api_key=5b3ce3597851110001cf62483bc257e622284e54ae3004682db1a018&"
     resp = req.get(url, params=data, headers = {'Accept': 'application/json, application/geo+json, application/gpx+xml, img/png; charset=utf-8'})
     print(resp.status_code, resp.reason)
     print(resp.url)
     print(resp.text)
```

Thank you!

Comment: What do you have tried so far?

Comment: i've tried to get request in raw data with this params
```request = {'api_key': '5b3ce3597851110001cf62483bc257e622284e54ae3004682db1a018', 'coordinates': '50.33522415,30.95192909|50.33576900,30.95166500', 'profile': 'driving-car'}
resp = req.get("https://api.openrouteservice.org/directions", params=request )```

Comment: As a result i've got an arabic output but i want to make it for Ukraine only

Comment: I've tried to take the data from file but it doesn't work my code is in edit @Kampi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have a file with the following pattern:

```
"drXY:48.94205856,38.48511505","fromXY:48.94167600,38.49207300",distInM:511 
"drXY:46.54586411,30.64417267","fromXY:46.53338808,30.65455914",distInM:1599 
"drXY:50.06436157,31.44526100","fromXY:50.07415641,31.45929694",distInM:1482 
"drXY:50.35911942,30.94097710","fromXY:50.33576900,30.95166500",distInM:2706
```

Then you can read the file line by line and use `strip` to remove `CRLF` etc. You can replace all non-numerical characters by using the `sub` method and in the last step you split your line at each `,`. This procedure results in the given example code:

```
import re

with open("Input.txt", "r") as File:
        Line = File.readline()
        while Line:
                Line = Line.strip()
                Line = re.sub(r"[a-zA-Z:\"]", r"", Line)
                LineSplit = Line.split(",")

                Line = File.readline()

                print("X: {} Y: {} | X: {} Y: {} | Distance: {}".format(LineSplit[0], LineSplit[1], LineSplit[2], LineSplit[3], LineSplit[4]))
```

Your result is a `List` with the numbers in your file.

```
X: 48.94205856 Y: 38.48511505 | X: 48.94167600 Y: 38.49207300 | Distance: 511
X: 46.54586411 Y: 30.64417267 | X: 46.53338808 Y: 30.65455914 | Distance: 1599
X: 50.06436157 Y: 31.44526100 | X: 50.07415641 Y: 31.45929694 | Distance: 1482
X: 50.35911942 Y: 30.94097710 | X: 50.33576900 Y: 30.95166500 | Distance: 2706
```

Now you can apply any sort of processing to this data.

Comment: Okay, i've got list index out of range. What's that supposed to mean?

Comment: My list is about 30000 rows with this kind of information

Comment: You can use other formats too. Maybe a `numpy.array` is a better solution for large amount of data. You can convert the string data into numbers to reduce the size of the list. This would help too.